# Language and learning of an MMO Game server

Tags: mmo, server, .net

I am creating a MMO using XNA framework for the client and want to create the server using .Net sockets in C#. I am not a total rookie to network programming, but I am having trouble finding resources, and learning material on developing a game server or learning .Net Sockets. I scanned the MSDN library for quite a while but I feel a tutorial or a step by step book would not go amiss. I considered a WCF program for the server but I want a more educated persons opinion before traveling down that road.

What do you think? Is there a reference I overlooked? Would WCF be appropriate?

Comment: I would look on source of server emulator of game you already know and learn from that. Like www.runuo.com for ultima online :)

Answer (score 3):

[This creators club thread](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/93072/557791.aspx) suggests that WCF has some unnecessary overhead compared to just using the lower level socket API.

Have you looked at a third party library like [Photon](http://www.exitgames.com/Pricing)? They're built on top of Enet (C++) and allow you to add logic via .NET. They handle providing infrastructure like message channels, packaging multiple messages, and reliable UDP. There's also [Lidgren](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/).

Ryzom is a MMORPG that has [open sourced their game](http://dev.ryzom.com/projects/ryzom/wiki).

And be sure to check GameDev.net's section on [multiplayer programming](http://www.gamedev.net/forum/15-multiplayer-and-network-programming/).